# What is the word for this context?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

> In the global rankings for scientific output, the number of documents and the number of citable documents are ———— of merely quantitative implications, while the number of citations, the ratio of self citations to external citations, and h-index are ———— that have qualitative implications as well.

What is the best choice for the blank? *Criteria, scale, indicator, measure, measurement*, or something else? What are such things called?

Comment: Where is this from?

Comment: @NVZ nowhere. It’s mine.

Comment: You want the same word in both blanks? Also it depends on tone and context: you have a choice of using something meaning "rough indication" or something meaning "exact measure".

Comment: "Implications" doesn't seem to me to work well, especially for the first half of the sentence. What would those two indicators (I assume that you want something like that for the blank) imply? Are the implications themselves quantitative?

Comment: @StuartF yes. Exactly same word.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan for the first blank only quantitative, for the second also qualitative.

Comment: @Sasan Yes, that's obvious. But "implications" still doesn't seem to be the right word.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Maybe not. But my question is about the blanks. I need a word the means ‘indicator’. Is ‘indicator’ itself any good?

Answer (score 1):

> (OALD) **index** plural indices  /ˈɪndɪsiːz/  a sign or measure that something else can be judged by
> • The number of new houses being built is a good index of a country's prosperity.

• In the global rankings for scientific output, the number of documents and the number of citable documents are *indices* of merely quantitative implications, while the number of citations, the ratio of self citations to external citations, and h-index are *indices* that have qualitative implications as well.